# Subdomain or domain?

Tags: seo, subdomain

We have more than one content management system (eCommerce) running on our site and we want to know would it be wise to separate these systems and run on their own server for better performance, easier to manage and better for security, but our concern is the SEO impact.

Is it better to run `site.com/this-is-our-other-platform/` or `this-is-our-other-platform.site.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep them both on the same domain. By doing that, all "trust" and "authority" will remain with your older domain. The new wholesale site should also get a bit of a quicker start with rankings because it's starting on an older, established domain.

If you were to start from scratch with a new domain, you'd also end up having to 301 pages from the old domain to the new one, which could risk lowering the old domain's PR if the wholesale links had a significant amount of incoming links.

Comment: So stick with Wholesale.hotbuckles.com?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. Will also make the transition simpler in the future if you decide to go back for whatever reason.

Answer (score -2):

We would recommend utilising an ecommerce platform that offers multi-store setup and create a retail store and a wholesale store. Magento offers a powerful multi-store setup.

You can then specify the wholesale store to be located on the same domain or different domain, whichever you prefer. We'd recommend setting up domain mapping so that your wholesale store appears at a different domain but both stores would use the same back office, catalog, content etc etc and you just specify the overrides as required for the wholesale store. This would also work on a sub domain.

Whether a separate domain or the same domain works better for you though, really depends on the differences between the retail store and the wholesale store.

Comment: Sorry, This is not an option - Both stores are on different platforms